# How to maintain quotes while exploding json in spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column in string format like below:

```
["name": "XXX","active": true,"locale": "EN","Channel":["1","2"]]
```

I would like to explode them like below in spark sql(preserving the quotes in string values).

This is code I used:

```
SELECT EXPLODE(from_json(col, 'map<string, string>>'))
FROM XXX;
```

I am not able to preserve the quotes in "XXX" and "EN" after exploding.

This is what I want:

| key | value |
| --- | --- |
| name | "XXX" |
| active | true |
| locale | "EN" |
| Channel | [1,2] |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes are part of the JSON representation of the data and not the data itself.  If there were embedded quotes in the data it would look like:

```
"\"SOME DATA\""
```

If you need to add quotes on strings, you can always concatenate them to the specific columns.  You can use the concat operator to accomplish this, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#concat

Alternatively, you can use get_json_object, which allows you to extract specific parts of a JSON object.  https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.get_json_object.html

Comment: Thank you. If I use Presto function json_extract(col, '$.name'), I could see "XXX". But If I use Spark function get_json_object(col, '$.name'), I can only see XXX.

Comment: I'll edit my answer, but you can use a different json function to get part of JSON instead of explode.